# How to install LSPServer for Vue+Pug in NeoVim editor?

Tags: neovim

I have a question for advanced Wimers/Neowimers on setting up Syntax, tabs and LSP for Pug inside a Vue component.

Recently moved from PhpStorm and Vscode to Nvim with AstroNvim config.
But there are some difficulties in customizing this editor for my technology stack that I use in my work.

For JavaScript I use LSP tsserver, I love it!
For Vue, I tried to use Volar, but it only works if we use the usual markup in the vue file, I couldn’t make friends with Pug,

My project has an index.vue file

```
<template lang="pug">
    section.cabinet
        .container
            h2 lorem ipsum
```

In this case, Volar will show that it was expecting a different token.

```
<template lang="pug">
    section.cabinet__agency_info [VOLAR]=> Undefined Syntax Token
```

That is, he expected to see such markup

```
<template lang="pug">
    <section class="cabinet__agency_info">
```

The question is how to make him friends with Pug so that he does not show that there is an error

There is also a nuance with Sass/Scss
Couldn't find language-parser for Sass, but found for Scss, installed it and installed language-parser for Css
Syntax highlighting works for Sass but only in sass files inside vue it doesn't work
For example, if we have such markup in the file

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
    .dropdown.phones
        button, label
            span[data-image]
```

What is inside the Style tag, it does not highlight in any way!

In general, Nvim is configured for Backend.
The global question is how to configure Nvim for Frontend,